# Pre-build step in eclipse (CDT)

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use a pre-build step in eclipse in CDT. According to description here: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_settings_steps.htm

> The pre-build step is not executed if the state of the main build is
>   determined to be up to date; otherwise it is executed. An attempt to
>   execute the main build will occur regardless of the success or failure
>   of executing the pre-build step.

I have 2 problems with it: 
1. The pre-build step is always executed even if the main build has nothing to build.
2. The prebuild step is executed after the main build.

Is this a bug or I am just doing something wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: It seems that pre-build step is always executed (tried it in 3.7 and 4.3), but post-build only if something need to build. This should be reported at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi?product=CDT. However order is correct for me.

Comment: Thank you for testing. Did you create a new project for the test or used one of yours? Woul it be possible to send me a zip of the project so I can test with the same project? Also what system are you on, windows or linux? Thanks a lot!

Comment: On linux. Just created a project via file -> new c project -> hello world ansi c project. Then went to project properties -> c/c++ build -> Settings -> Build steps and added echo "pre-build" to pre-build commands, and echo "post-build" to post-build commands, etc. I can send a project, but there is nothing else in there.

Comment: For others who stumble into this: it has been [reported to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419428), probably by the topic starter. Feedback was asked, but never given, so the issue seems pretty dead at the moment.